# Limit the number of characters that can be used in the custom message of a bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I recently found a bounty question with a custom message so long that it made me stop and think about what the OP was thinking when they were writing the message.

[image: Bounty Message]

To me, a lot of this could probably be edited into the question, or added as comments.  I think we should limit the number of allowed characters in the custom message of a bounty, or provide messaging to make it clear that this space should be used for setting the expectations of a perspective answer, and not for question clarification.

Comment: I would expect something in the 300 character range should be sufficient, at most, match the comment character limit at 600.

Comment: I don't even want to read that for 50 rep.

Comment: On the contrary, they [should add line breaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I still think 3000 characters is excessive for the purpose of this message.  If you're entering that many, you should probably be editing the question.

Comment: Not if you're not the original author.

Comment: Voting to close that bounty message as too broad.. wait... that's impossible... dammit...

Comment: @JoshCaswell If you're not the original author and you have that much to say, your question is probably different enough to warrant a completely new one, with a detailed example on what your have tried and how your example differs and requires that much explanation.

Comment: Just get rid of bounties

Comment: So I can just paste the full text of a book in there?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238456/242209), you're limited to 3000 characters.

Comment: some stats http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/744747#graph to support @servy's expectation.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177501/reduce-character-limit-for-bounty-custom-text

Comment: Is it possible for paragraphs to be included in custom bounty messages? If not, maybe that would be an idea?